# Reading File in Python and putting column into Array

Tags: python, arrays, file, csv

I am fairly new to Python and am working with the NLTK to produce a sound dynamic Text Analyzer.  I have a .csv file with member information, survey response number, and survey response text that I need open and read.

I have:

```
import csv
import codecs

f = open('testresponseFS.csv')
raw = f.read()
print raw
```

This may be a bit over my head, but I want to read each row in the file to keep all information intact, and read a specific cell "response" which contains text response. I have been suggested put that specific column in an array, iterating through the whole column with array values; therefore I can run functions on each item in that array, and eventually append those values back to the .csv file next to the "response".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv

# read data
with open('testresponseFS.csv', 'rb') as inf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf)
    header = next(incsv)
    data = [row for row in incsv]

# process data
header.append('Comments')
response_column = 4
for row in data:
    response = row[response_column]
    newval = response[:4].lower()    # or whatever you do to it
    row.append(newval)   

# write data back out
with open('finaldata.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
    outcsv.writerow(header)
    outcsv.writerows(data)
```